# When Using Map(), How to Select the Name of Each Column?

Tags: r

I intend to write a function that plots a histogram for numeric columns in the dataframe using R. However, the problem is I do not know how to choose the name of that column as histogram's title. For example, the title of "age" column should be "Histogram of age". Can you guys give me some advice? Thanks very much.

```
# Plot histograms for x
hist_numeric <- function(x){
  if (is.numeric(x) | is.integer(x)){
    hist(x, main = "???")
  } else {
    message("Not integer or numeric varible")
  }
}
# plot histograms for every column in the dataframe
map(df, hist_numeric)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `colnames` to put the column names into a list prior to the function call and then use `map2` to call multiple arguments for the function:

```
hist_numeric <- function(x, name){
  if (is.numeric(x) | is.integer(x)){
    hist(x, main = name)
  } else {
    message("Not integer or numeric varible")
  }
}

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50),
                 y = letters[1:10],
                 z = runif(50))
names_col <- colnames(df)    

map2(.x = df, .y = names_col, .f = hist_numeric)
```